# Problem of installing kobuki in turtlebot installation (Indigo)

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a problem when I install kobuki in turtlebot installation of indigo. Following the tutorial, there was nothing wrong with rocon. However, when I continued to kobuki and run "rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y", I got the following error messages:

`$ rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y

 ...

executing command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-indigo-kobuki-apps]

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-kobuki-apps

ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install

  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-indigo-kobuki-apps] failed`

The packages before "ros-indigo-kobuki-apps" (e.g., "ros-indigo-move-base-msgs") were installed without an error when running "rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y", but "ros-indigo-kobuki-apps" cannot be located.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190137/problem-of-installing-kobuki-in-turtlebot-installation-(indigo)/) by [kevinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/5755/kevinma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the kobuki_apps package was released quite recently and isn't available in the public repository yet: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html?q=kobuki

I would wait for the next synchronization announcement on the ros-users mailing list and then try again, or install kobuki_apps from source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0